# Agrupar resultados mySQL

Tags: mysql, query, group-by, highcharts

Boa noite, preciso fazer uma consulta na tabela abaixo:

[image: tabela]

Mas que me traga o resultado de quantos type = E , type = S agrupado por mês, esse resultado eu vou jogar em um gráfico que vai exibir por mês quantas entrada e saída;

Segue codigo pra criar a tabela :

```
CREATE TABLE `movements` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('S','E') NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `movements_product_idx` (`id_product`),
  KEY `movements_user_idx` (`id_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `movements_product` FOREIGN KEY (`id_product`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `movements_user` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Tentei esse código, está agrupando por mês mas não sei quantas type='S' ou 'E' tive nesse mês;

```
select count(id)Total, DATE_FORMAT (`date`,'%b') AS `mes` from movements group by month(date);
```

Se alguém souber como faz agradeço...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, creio que:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%b') AS `mes`, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TypeE, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TypeS 
FROM movements 
GROUP BY month(date);
```

possa atende-lo.

Comment: Cara valeu, isso mesmo, funcionou aqui!